# Laravel Excel Formula Error: Unexpected operator '='

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel Excel Maatwebsite package. When I try to read to excel I am getting this error:

```
 Formula Error: Unexpected operator '='
```

How can disable read formula in this package.I want to only get field value from excel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) you can enable / disable calculating formulas like this:

```
// Enable calculation
$reader->calculate();

// Disable calculation
$reader->calculate(false);
```

Comment: will this also avoid calculation in Excel or only during export?

Answer (score 0):

If the calculate config is `false` and you face the problem yet, you should extend `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\StringValueBinder` class and implement `Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomValueBinder` interface in your class.
It cause PhpSpreadsheet behave with the data in sheet as **string**.

Package [Document](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#disable-intelligent-formatting)